# How can I get the standard error of parameters from FindFit?

Tags: fitting

I used [`FindFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) with Norm function as written below.

```
fittedvalue = 
FindFit[DataEXP, function, {A, B}, tN1, 
  Method -> NMinimize, NormFunction -> (Norm[#, Infinity] &)]
```

How can I get the standard errors of obtained parameters?

[`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) is not available with [`NormFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormFunction.html) so that shows different parameters.

Comment: Possibly the only option is to use a bootstrap approach.

Comment: Can you share your rationale for wanting to use this norm function in a regression?